# Question on the where method in a search page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the code below, what is the bracket in "%[#{search}]%" doing? Is it only getting the content in the bracket in search and comparing it gas or it is only getting the content in the bracket of the gas and comparing to gas?

`.where("gas LIKE ?", "%[#{search}]%")`

Answer (score 0):

The brackets would be treated as strings.
If search = 'oxygen' Your query would look like

> WHERE gas LIKE '%[oxygen]%'